# How do I get Medium Debris Pack?

Tags: astroneer

I need a medium debris pack for the exo launcher or whatever it's called.  I've figured out how to get debris bundles, and small debris packs, but I can't figure out how to get medium debris packs.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a Packager on a large enough piece of debris.

According to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CqlqTSBKiwM):

> Larger items, such as the Medium Rover wrecks, EXO Dynamic Research Aid tops and Pyramid tops will turn into a Medium Debris Pack.